# Count items to different styles

Tags: php

im using $count on wordpress to count my posts to different style.

I have three items on each row, so i have to put margin-left: 0 in the first item for each row. So i ll put on first, fourth item, tenth item ....

like this: 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16....

how can i count this?

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=lookbook'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : $count = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
<div class="lookbookall marginleftnone">
<?php elseif (($count % 4) ==0) : ?>
<div class="lookbookall marginleftnone">
<?php else : ?>      
<div class="lookbookall">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with pure CSS. Use `:nth-child(3n)` for the selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is: !(($count-1)%3) or ($count-1)%3==0 (This is the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

`if ($count%3 == 0)` is all you need. You don't repeat it for each number, modulo is the remaining after division. (This assumes a 0-based array.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($count%3 == 1){ ?>
<div class="lookbookall marginleftnone">
<?php }else{ ?>
<div class="lookbookall">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: and you can also use CSS for this purpose as kojiro said